# Repeated requests when I use struts2 to submit form

Tags: java, struts2

My project is build on struts2.Recently I found a problem that is when I submit my form,sometimes the request send 2 times.
my code:

```
document.searchForm.action = "${dynamicURL}/voucher/doAddIniAccountVoucherMake.action";

var para=$('#searchForm').serialize();

$('#para').val(para);
document.searchForm.submit();
```

In the method of the action,I log the time and param in database.Actually ,the Repeated requests is bare,but it did happen.I want to konw the reason of this problem, because it will cause big problem in procudution enviroment.Someone can give any means?

Comment: There's no way to help with the information provided.

Comment: Without additional information; my 2 guesses are, you have a javascript event running multiple times and therefore submitting the form more than 1x, or the button is being double clicked.